# Problems explaining questions

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TeX math markup is sorely needed](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2/tex-math-markup-is-sorely-needed)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TeX math markup is sorely needed](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2/tex-math-markup-is-sorely-needed)

Hi, I visit this site and I see that many users facing problems in explaining the terms or mathematical symbols like for limit, root, sqrt, square, belongs to etc.

Can stackexchange provide such symbols just like the facility to bold the text, Italic, link or image etc.

I don't know how but this will make some explanation easy for users.

Comment: It is needed. Until we get real LaTeX support, the easiest workaround is to use [this greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/81977) by John Gietzen.